# Polymer 1.0 two-way binding to an Array change event not firing

Tags: arrays, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have an array property in my element which is populated from an outer element via Ajax. The 'someProperty' property from an object in the Array is bound to an input field, and the data shows correctly. But when I change the input field value, it is not reflected back in the Array. I also tried iron-input without any success.

```
<template>
  <input value="{{arrayItem(pageData.*, currentPage, 'someProperty')::input}}">
</template>

Polymer({
  is: 'book-content',

  properties: {
    pageData: {
      type: Array,
      value: function() {
        return [];
      },
      notify: true
    },
    currentPage: {
      type: Number,
      value: 1
    }
  },

  observers: [
    'dataChanged(pageData.*)'
  ],

  dataChanged: function(changeRecord) {
    console.log('change');// this does not get fired
  },

  arrayItem: function(change, index, path) {
    return this.get(path, change.base[index]);
  },

});
```

The above element is contained inside an element which makes an ajax call and then uses **.set** to populate the pageData property in the above child element. The data looks like this:

```
[{'someProperty': 'abc'}, {'someProperty': 'def'}]
```

Comment: Here is example in which there is binding between array and input fields, it may help: http://plnkr.co/edit/8AyRgrFyY7RUTCKs2dW3?p=preview